# What does [x*="y"] and [x^="y"] mean in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was wondering if what's the meaning of * and ^ in creating a class in css?.

For example:

```
[class*="sample-"]
```

and

```
[class^="sample-"]
```

Comment: "class" just happens to be the name of the particular attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*=` means find all elements where the **text "sample-" exists somewhere in the class attribute**. For example:

```
<style>
    [class*="sample-"] {}
</style>

<p class="asdsadsample-adas">Matches</p>
<p class="smple-">Doesn't match</p>
```

`^=` This means find all elements where the **class attribute begins with the text "sample-"**. For example

```
<style>
    [class^="sample-"] {}
</style>

<p class="sample-blah">Matches</p>
<p class="ssample-blah">Doesn't match</p>
```